# There's no ntpd in centos 7, how to sync time automatically and manually with chrony?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, ntp, time-synchronization

Seems there's no ntpd in centos7, how can I sync time in centos7?

I found out that `chrony` should be used in centos7, what is manual way to update time using chrony?

I assume chronyd is something equivalent to ntpd? and what's the command equivalent to `ntpdate -s time.nist.gov`?

Comment: There exists an ntp package providing ntpd, it is not the default in RHEL 7. chrony is a perfectly fine implementation for most use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've changed chrony's configuration, you don't need to do anything but start the service.

```
systemctl enable --now chronyd.service
```

The default configuration automatically steps the clock at startup (using the `makestep` directive) if it is more than one second different than the default NTP servers.

---

If you explicitly removed `makestep` from the configuration, you can step the clock by using the command

```
chronyc makestep
```

You should *NOT* do this if you used the non-default `rtcfile` option though, as it will cause the RTC drift to be recorded incorrectly.

---

For further details see the [RHEL 7 chrony documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-Configuring_NTP_Using_the_chrony_Suite).